# LZ4 not found for CMake on Android Studio

Tags: android, cmake, openvpn, lz4

I'm trying to compile OpenVPN library inside Android, but I'm getting this error:

```
C/C++ debug|x86 : CMake Error at /home/user/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.10.2.4988404/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
  Could NOT find LZ4 (missing: LZ4_LIBRARY LZ4_INCLUDE_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/user/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.10.2.4988404/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:378 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /home/user/orwell2/deps/libopenvpn3/openvpn3/cmake/FindLZ4.cmake:5 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  /home/user/orwell2/deps/libopenvpn3/openvpn3/cmake/findcoredeps.cmake:84 (find_package)
  /home/user/orwell2/deps/libopenvpn3/src/libopenvpn/CMakeLists.txt:24 (add_core_dependencies)
Affected Modules: app
```

This is the `FindLZ4.cmake` file:

```
find_path(LZ4_INCLUDE_DIR NAMES lz4.h)
find_library(LZ4_LIBRARY NAMES lz4)

include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)
FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS(
        LZ4 DEFAULT_MSG
        LZ4_LIBRARY LZ4_INCLUDE_DIR)

mark_as_advanced(LZ4_INCLUDE_DIR LZ4_LIBRARY)
```

I installed `liblz4-dev` on my debian10.

When I run this outside of Android Studio:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
find_library(LZ4_LIBRARY NAMES lz4)
message(STATUS, ${LZ4_LIBRARY})
```

I get the path of the `liblz4` file. Why on Android Studio it fails?

Comment: problem was that LZ4 is on my computer but only for x84_64 architecture, not ARM

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to install the lz4 dev package instead of the regular one, here is the command:

```
sudo apt install -y liblz4-dev
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: worked for me on Ubuntu 20 machine